# bootstrap fixed position button

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

```html
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-2">
  Panel for filter
</div>
 <div class="col-lg-6">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-md" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#product" style="margin-right:10px">my button</button>
 then i show the contents  
 </div>
  </div>
```

I have a row in bootstrap. The row is divided into two parts. One is a div for filter panel and second is to show some content.

I have a button in the second part `(bootstrap modal button)`. In the navigation breadcrumb, I'm giving an option to hide the filter panel.

All works fine. My problem is that when I hide the first div, In the **filter panel my button in the second div also changes the position**.

My requirement is that if I hide the filter panel, the button in the second div should not change even though the contents in the second div changes.

Does anyone know any workaround to achieve the desired result?

Comment: Show some code, so we can help.

Comment: without code how can we help you?

Comment: filter panel and content im showing using rest api calls.

Comment: everything is working. but how can i make the button position fixed. i tried with position:fixed; it didnt worked.

Comment: where are you trying to position it. top-right or top-left

Comment: This row is in the middle of the page.I want the button to be at extreme right of the row

Comment: Now what happens is that when i hide the filter panel . my contents and the button moves. i Want the content to move but the button should be fixed at the right side itself there should not be anychange in the button position

Comment: try to give button with style `float:right` may be it can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
$('button').click(function(){
  $('#panel').toggleClass('inactive');
});
```

```css
#panel{
  background-color:red;
  height:100px;
  display:block;
}
#panel.inactive{
  display:none;
}
#content{
  position:relative;
  background-color:green;
  height:100px;
}
.btn{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  right:0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-2" id="panel">
  Panel for filter
</div>
 <div class="col-lg-6" id="content">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-md" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#product" style="margin-right:10px">my button</button>
 then i show the contents  
 </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason that the element (your button) moves can be caused by the different interpretation of `position: fixed;` on a few mobile devices. 
I have experienced that the fixed element in question can not be a child-element of any moving (eg. scrolling) element. On desktop this seems not a problem. So you should place the button outside of the row or if needed inside just

```
position: absolute;
top:10px;
right: 10px;
```

or so as stated by kittyCat

A next reason could be: if you hide the first part of your row `col-lg-2` then there are two grid-cells missing to the line. So just hide the content of the row:
So take the Example of kittyCat and change:

```
<div class="col-lg-2" id="panel">
  Panel for filter
</div>
```

to

```
<div class="col-lg-2" >
<div id="panel">  Panel for filter</div>
</div>
```

and it should work as wanted.

Or if you need the space and you want to hide the `col-lg-2` then change the class of the second element from `col-lg-6` to `col-lg-8`.